# private static int[] wordLengths(String[] words)

Tags: java

I am confused as to what the return statement should be.

This is what I have:

```
private static int[] wordLengths(String[] words)
{
    String[] words = in.nextLine();
    String[] array = 0;

    if(words > 0)
    {
        int[] wordLengths = words.length();
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: If you need the length of a String just do word.Length

Comment: You know this program is not correct. Try to explain more what you want to do first so people can help you.

Comment: I think the rest of us are confused too.  What the `return` statement should be depends on what your routine is expected to do. Can you tell us that?

Comment: It appears to me that you're confused as to what _every_ statement should be.  There are so many problems with this code, that I don't think it will help you if we give you just the one answer.  You need to sit with a tutor or someone else with experience, and let them explain the details of how to write the code.

Answer (score 0):

The code above is having too much problem:

You need get word length => then return an int **not** int[]

You method param has: `String[] words` then you can not daclare it again in the method body

`words` is an array cannot use to compare `if(words > 0)`

As your method name, you just need the simple code:

```
public static int wordLengths(String[] words)
{
    return words.length;
}
```

Comment: Her method name is `wordLengths`, and your code only returns one length.  I'm guessing the answer is not that simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int[] wordLengths(String[] words)
{
    int[] wordLengths = new int[words.length];
    for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++){
        wordLengths[i]=words[i].length();
    }
    return wordLengths;
}
```